# How to increase audio volume?

Tags: android

Using my Android 4.0 phone I usually listen to audiobooks when I'm in the car. I use my headphones, but sometimes the highest volume is not enough.

How can I increase the maximum volume on an Android phone?

Comment: Seemingly stupid question, but I wonder if the [european regulations on maximum volume](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_IP-09-1364_en.htm?locale=en) has something to do with this

Comment: I don't think so, maximum volume on my phone sounds like 50% volume on my ipod.

Comment: See [How to increase music playback volume?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1766) and [How can I increase the maximum speaker volume?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/19426)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's only possible to increase the volume of your device out of the range specified by the vendor and have good sound, when you have root access on the device. But you have to be careful with increasing the volume out of the range specified by the vendor, so that you don't damage the speaker. Or doing this can also decrease the lifetime of your speakers and your device. So, I think it's not a very good idea to do this.

But, I've found an how-to how you can increase the volume out of the specified range (not tested by my own) if you have root access on your device: http://androidadvices.com/increase-volume-android-mobile-phones/